# IDA - floating point operand type

Tags: ida

How do I set the data to floating point number in quickier way than clicking on:

```
Edit>Operand type>Number>Floating point
```

I have a lot of wrongly detected casual DWORD's instead of Float's and clicking on every single of them with above is a giant waste of time.

How can I automate this process, or setup a shortcut for floating point numbers? For example, how 'B' for binary or 'D' for byte/word/dword work by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for data items: <kbd>Alt-D, F</kbd>
2. Menu: Options|Shortcuts..., add a custom shortcut for OpFloat action.

Answer (score 2):

Type **Alt+D** to open up data type setup and check **"4 Float"**.

Now every time you cycle through **D** on binary you will end up with one more datatype after dword which is float